# Linking with Python and OpenCv

Tags: python, linux, opencv, cmake

I am writing a program in `python` using `OpenCv` libraries. My project folder is Foo and inside i have an image and the executable. My `CmakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Foo)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable(Foo Im.py)
target_link_libraries(Foo ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${python2.7} )
```

When i execute `cmake .` i get the following error:

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: Foo
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "Foo".
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user_name/OpenCv/Foo
```

I am using python 2.7 and linux 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake is used to compile source code (C++ or C code for example).

The OpenCV library can be used with C, C++ or Python.
Here I guess that you want to use Python with the OpenCV library so you should not need CMake because Python is an interpreted language, not a compiled one like C++.

You can execute your script with the command:

```
python3 path/to/your/script.py
```

or if you use the previous version of the language (Python 2):

```
python2 path/to/your/script.py
```